# example code: A service calls CreateProcessAsUser() I want the process to run in the user's session, not session 0

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-services, createprocessasuser

I am seeking example code:

For a service calls CreateProcessAsUser() I want the process to run in the user's session, not session 0

thus far the created process is only running like a service in session 0

Answer (score 7):

This was stripped from some old code that launched a console app from a service.  It worked under NT4 but I haven't tested it with a modern version of Windows so can't guarantee it will work as it did on NT4.

EDIT: No, that's not going to work as-is.  You need to add the code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379608%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create a desktop, set the SID, etc.

```
    if (!LogonUser(userId,
                   domain,
                   password,
                   LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                   LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                   &hUserToken))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    if (!ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hUserToken))
    {
        DWORD rc = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(hUserToken);
        return rc;
    }

    STARTUPINFO             si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    rc = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserToken,                // user token
                           0,                           // app name
                           "foo.exe",                   // command line
                           0,                           // process attributes
                           0,                           // thread attributes
                           FALSE,                       // don't inherit handles
                           DETACHED_PROCESS,            // flags
                           0,                           // environment block
                           0,                           // current dir
                           &si,                         // startup info
                           &pi);                        // process info gets put here


    if (!rc)
    {
        DWORD rc = GetLastError();
        RevertToSelf();
        CloseHandle(hUserToken);
        return rc;
    }

    RevertToSelf();
    CloseHandle(hUserToken);

    return 0;
```

Comment: You do not need to create a new desktop. You specify an existing desktop in the `STARTUPINFO` structure, such as the user's interactive `WinSta0\Default` desktop (as shown in Microsoft's example).  And you do not really need to mess around with SIDs, either.  `CreateProcessAsUser()` in a service can work fine without them. I have been using it in services for years without any problem, and I do not manipulate SIDs for it. On the other hand, I do not use `LogonUser()` or `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`, I use `WTSQueryUserToken()` and `DuplicateTokenEx()` instead.

Comment: Also, you should call `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` before calling `CreateProcessAsUser()` as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree (somewhat). Perhaps you should write a new answer. It's a three-year old answer with no acceptance and no votes, up or down, so I'm reluctant to spend more time on it right now.

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the user token obtained via `WTSQueryUserToken`. It already returns you a primary token

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an ancient post but I happen to be working on this so here's some code that works for me.

Determine the session ID of the currently logged-on user

```
DWORD GetCurrentSessionId ()
{
    WTS_SESSION_INFO *pSessionInfo;
    DWORD n_sessions = 0;
    BOOL ok = WTSEnumerateSessions (WTS_CURRENT_SERVER, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &n_sessions);
    if (!ok)
        return 0;

    DWORD SessionId = 0;

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < n_sessions; ++i)
    {
        if (pSessionInfo [i].State == WTSActive)
        {
            SessionId = pSessionInfo [i].SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }

    WTSFreeMemory (pSessionInfo);
    return SessionId;
}
```

Launch process as the currently logged-on user

```
bool LaunchProcess (const char *process_path)
{
    DWORD SessionId = GetCurrentSessioId ();
    if (SessionId == 0)    // no-one logged in
        return false;

    HANDLE hToken;
    BOOL ok = WTSQueryUserToken (SessionId, &hToken);
    if (!ok)
        return false;

    void *environment = NULL;
    ok = CreateEnvironmentBlock (&environment, hToken, TRUE);

    if (!ok)
    {
        CloseHandle (hToken);
        return false;
    }

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof (si) } ;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { } ;
    si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";

    // Do NOT want to inherit handles here
    DWORD dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
    ok = CreateProcessAsUser (hToken, process_path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        dwCreationFlags, environment, NULL, &si, &pi);

    DestroyEnvironmentBlock (environment);
    CloseHandle (hToken);

    if (!ok)
        return false;

    CloseHandle (pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle (pi.hProcess);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am facing an undefinde error for `WTSActive` and `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER`

Comment: The documentation at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsa) always tells you what header file(s) you need to #include and what .libs you need to link against.  Sorry that isn't in my post.

Comment: using Can I impersonate logged on user using `WTSQueryUserToken` token ?

Comment: I believe that `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` will accept such a token, yes.  I suggest you give it a go.

Comment: Is it mandatory to set `si.lpDesktop` to `winsta0\\default`?

Comment: @LouisBernard IDK sorry.  You'd have to experiment.

Comment: @PaulSanders Could you please let me know how to get the hToken from the security context or windowsIdentity object. Please help me to solve this issue/blocker. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070791/impersonating-user-in-remote-machine-and-creating-a-process-as-logged-in-user

Comment: @ChandruT Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking me.  That question is all about Java and I don't use that.